# Related to java design patterns - technical aptitude

Tags: java, design-patterns

1. Connection pool is a example of which design pattern. ? **FLY Weigh**t -I think
2. Java io library is a example of which design pattern. ? – **Decorator** - I think
3. Company X is using a library bought from Company Y. But Y has now closed out. So company X bought similar library from Company Z and found that many of the classes are having differnet interfaces compared to the library from Y. What design pattern should be applied by company X to handle this situation? **Adapter** - i think
4. In company XYZ, transfer between data center and users have become slow due to less bandwidth. Which design pattern should the programmer apply to sent data efficiently over the low bandwidth network?

   - Front controller & Business Delegate
   - Service locator and data access objects
   - Session Facade and Value objects - i think
   - Service to worker and Service locator.
5. One diagram given for a design pattern where
               AbstractInterface is a interface which contains method A()
               class1 and class2 extends from Abstract interface and class2 overrides methodA(). 
               It is mentioned that call from client comes to AbstractInterface and the interface delegates the call to respective child classes. **Which design pattern is this?**

Answer (score 1):

1. A connection pool use the [*Object Pool Pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern). It differs from the flyweight because objects can be modified. [Flyweight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) use immutable instances.
2. Often the [*decorator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern is used on the IO libraries, but not only it.
3. Yes [*adapter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) is the right answer.
4. If the problem is related to the format of data that needs too much bandwidth, changing it to a different format can be done using an [*Adapter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern). The object sent from client to server are [*value objects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object). Also using a cache can be useful to send data only if needed. To perform a cache that updates automatically when the data are changed on the back end you can use an [*Observer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)
5. If I understood well the [*delegation pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern).